# Why doesn't the template work with std::string

Tags: c++, string, templates, stl, instantiation

I have the following template:

```
template <typename TData>
inline void CFileOperations::load_and_save_data(TData& value)
{
   assert( (mIStream != nullptr) != /*XOR*/ (mOStream != nullptr) );

   if ( this->is_loading() ) {
      *mIStream >> value;
   } else {
      *mOStream << value << " "; // space is required to separate values for load.
   }
}
```

It won't compile if I call it for std::string:

std::string s;
obj->load_and_save(s);

Compile-time error (Visual Studio):

*CHexEngineParams.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __cdecl CFileOperations::load_and_save_data(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > &)" (?load_and_save_data@CFileOperations@@IEAAXAEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl CHexEngineParams::load_and_save(void)" (?load_and_save@CHexEngineParams@@UEAAXXZ)*

To make it work, I need an extra specialization, which is a copy/paste of the template:

```
inline void CFileOperations::load_and_save_data(std::string& value)
{
   assert( (mIStream != nullptr) != /*XOR*/ (mOStream != nullptr) );

   if ( this->is_loading() ) {
      *mIStream >> value;
   } else {
      *mOStream << value << " "; // space is required to separate values for load.
   }
}
```

Why doesn't the std::string's call get its instantiation from the template?

Comment: Is the function being declared in a header file and the code you have shown here defined in a cpp file?

Comment: No, everything is in the header file (because template and inline).  The template works for basic types as well as with STL containers (with << and >> operators overloading), so that's not the issue.  Only std::string is an issue.

Comment: We are going to need a [mre] then.

Comment: My bad: didn't remove the related specialized declaration in some multifaceted cleanup.  Was sure I did it.  That's what happens when you're interrupted in your work thousands times a day. :-( Solved.